# Increase Speed of Sorting Large List of Strings by Character in Java

Tags: java, list, performance, character, frequency

I have written a code to runs through a list of strings and returns a list of the least frequent characters found throughout the whole list of strings.

What would be the fastest way to return the list of the words sorted by those that contain the least frequent characters first? (I'm working with a huge list of strings, so the code I've written isn't running fast enough. The example below is just for example)

For example, if the given list is: `["hello", "my", "name", "is", "inigo", "montoya", "you", "killed", "my", "father", "prepare", "to", "die"]`. My code, returns : `[s, g, u, k, f, h, d, p, n, t, r, l, m, y, a, i, o, e]`, where `s` is the least frequent letter found in the list of strings, and `e` is the most frequent letter found in the list. The resulting list would then return the words containing the least frequent letter first and so on. For example: `["is", "inigo", "you", "killed", "father", "hello", "die", "prepare", "name", "montoya", "to", "my"]`

Here is my code that finds the least frequent letters:

```
    public static void method(List<String> words)
    {
        Map<Character, Integer> elemCount = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (String word : words)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i  < word.length(); i++)
            {
                if (elemCount.containsKey(word.charAt(i)))
                {
                    elemCount.put(word.charAt(i), elemCount.get(word.charAt(i)) + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    elemCount.put(word.charAt(i), 1);
                }
            }
        }
        ArrayList<Character> sortedElems = new ArrayList<>();
        LinkedList<String> sorted = new LinkedList<>();
        elemCount.entrySet().stream().sorted(
        Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).forEach(entry -> 
        { 
            for (int i = 1; i <= entry.getValue(); i++)
            {
                if (sortedElems.contains(entry.getKey()) == false)
                {
                    sortedElems.add(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
        );
```

And here is the code where I'm trying to sort by least frequent characters found in the string:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedElems.size(); i++)
        {
            for (String word : words)
            {
                char x = sortedElems.get(i);
                CharSequence c = x + "";
                if (word.contains(c) == true && sorted.contains(word) == false)
                {
                    sorted.add(word);

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sorted);
```

Comment: How long does it take now? How fast does it need to be?

Comment: I went to the grocery store and came back and nothing had printed in that amount of time. It needs to be optimally fast, as i'll be performing more loops on it within the program which will obviously decrease the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work pretty well.  I abandoned the streams approach as it was too slow.

```
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(List.of("hello", "my",
                "name", "is", "inigo", "montoya", "you", "killed",
                "my", "father", "prepare", "to", "die"));

        // frequency count.
        int[] chars = new int[256];
        for (String w : words) {
            for (char c : w.toCharArray()) {
                chars[c]++;
            }
        }
        // find minimum used character
        Map<String, Integer> mins = new HashMap<>();
        for (String w : words) {
            if (!mins.containsKey(w)) {
                int v = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                for (char c : w.toCharArray()) {
                    if (chars[c] < v) {
                        v = chars[c];
                    }
                }
                mins.put(w, v);
            }
        }

        Comparator<String> comp1 =
                (String a, String b) -> a.compareTo(b);
        Comparator<String> comp =
                (a, b) -> mins.get(a).compareTo(mins.get(b));
        comp = comp.thenComparing(comp1);

        // sort first on character then lexically
        words.sort(comp);
        words.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here is the frequency count

```
1=[f, g, k, s, u]
2=[d, h, p]
3=[n, r, t]
4=[a, l, m, y]
5=[i]
6=[o]
7=[e]
```

And the words in sorted order

```
father
inigo
is
killed
you
die
hello
prepare
montoya
name
to
my
my
```

Comment: This code isn't outputting as expected. It is only outputting a few words from the original list.

Comment: Which list.  I printed 13 words and you provided 13 words.

Comment: Actually, I think because you have two print lines it's causing only some to be displayed.

Comment: I reposted the code that I just ran to make certain.  The frequency count is formatted differently than yours.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I used the 13 words as an example, but I'm using a massive list of words in my program. I think I may have figured it out though after deleting the last print line

Comment: Also note that your output is slight different than mine because we handled "ties" differently.

Comment: Gotta run.  Hope this helped!

Comment: Ahh, yes now that makes sense, thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

These are my considerations that could not fit in a comment.

From your description, the general flow of the algorithm is the two-step process of scanning the array to generate the histogram and somehow sorting the array using histogram info.

The first step is unavoidable and cannot be further reduced unless the data arrives as stream directly from the source of these words. In that case you can simply update the histogram with barely any overhead as new words arrive.
Regardless, this was the easy part.

For the hard part, we can scan the array and insert each word (or a pointer to each word) into a b-tree whose splitting mechanism uses a Score computed on-the-fly using a simple function that takes as parameters the current word and the histogram.
Finally, scan the b-tree to extract the final array with all the words neatly sorted.

In a non-streaming scenario, the computational complexity would be close to `O(n+nlog(n)+n)`, however you can arrive at no more than `O(nlog(n))` if streaming is used for the original array AND you are satisfied with having a b-tree as your final product without needing to build an explicit final array.